# How can I stream a large Azure blob as chunks to clients using web API?

Tags: http, azure, asp.net-web-api, streaming, azure-blob-storage

I have users who need to be able to download very large zip files using my Web API endpoints. Some of these files can be over 1GB in size. The files themselves are stored as blobs in Azure. Obviously loading the entire stream will not work, especially with multiple users, as it is very likely I would run out of memory. So I need to somehow send it in chunks.

Can anyone explain/show me how this would work using Web API? I'm not sure how to write this. Or perhaps any other better suggestions on how to go about achieving my objective in a scalable fashion?

Here is an endpoint I have:

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetFile(int fileId)
{
    // TODO: somehow stream chunks from azure through to the client's browser...
}
```

A web browser is used to initiate the request with Web API. I would like to simply include an anchor tag on my HTML page that a user can click to download the file:

```
<a href='localhost/File?fileId=3'>Click here to download</a>
```

Comment: Can you tell us something about your Web API clients (essentially user agents)? Is it a browser-based application or a desktop/mobile application?

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. The web API is being accessed via web browser. Simple anchor tag.

Answer (score 1):

You should directly stream blobs via Azure Storage client library. You could also make a WebAPI call to get a SAS uri for the blob you want to download and then include that URI in your anchor tab.
If the Uri was constructed properly, the download will start as soon as the user clicks the link. This way you don't have to worry about memory issues with your web api as the content is being streamed directly from Azure storage.